# Party health bars flashing at random times?

Tags: xbox-one, torment-tides-of-numenera

Sometimes, without any particular reason (I think, at least none that I can think of), the health bars of my companions will flash with a yellow hue. They'll keep blinking for a while then they stop.

It never happens when I'm exploring a dungeon or during a crisis, mostly happens in "safe zones". Is it just a bug (playing on XB1) or does it mean anything at all?

Answer (score 2):

It is most probably the effect of the [Tide](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Tides) - is your major tide golden by any chance? On PC I've noticed that characters often glow (or are surrounded by a swirling glow) of gold (initially they were surrounded by other colors, it changed with time).

Comment: no, my major tide was indigo for that playthrough, plus the flashing stopped after a while. but I'm currently onto a red-tide game, so I'll see if the flashing is red-ish!